Signal Quintile Performance
I’m currently backtesting the performance of a signal (top - bottom quintile). The signal shows positive performance over monthly, quarterly, and annual rebalance horizons. However, the performance strictly increases as I rebalance less frequently.
I’m assuming this indicates that my signal is too volatile on a monthly basis. How can I reduce volatility on a monthly basis? Are there other tests I should be conducting on top of performance before making changes to my signal?
For context, I’ve already run attribution on the long/short portfolio (top quintile - bottom quintile), and it has little to no exposure to most Barra factors.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What do you mean the performance strictly increases? How do you measure performance?

? Hold the position for more than 1 month ?

@KaiSqDist I mean, the annualized out-of-sample performance long/short dollar neutral top quintile - bottom quintile is better rebalancing annual vs. quarterly vs. monthly.

@nbbo2 The signal isn't strategy-specific, it'll likely be used in a multifactor context.  I think the alpha is lower for more frequent rebalances, because the signal is too volatile.
